# Alamofire: Timeout not changing for SessionManager based on configuration

Tags: swift, alamofire

Here is my code attempting to change the timeout length when setting up my SessionManager:

```
private var defaultSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(120)
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: config)
}()
```

However, the timeout for the request is always 60 seconds (here is a screenshot curtsy of the iOS tool netfox):

[image: Netfox screenshot of a request]

I also tried configuring `timeoutIntervalForResource` to no success either.
Is this not the correct way to configure the timeout length for a request via SessionManager?  if so, how do I do so

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `timeoutIntervalForRequest` and `timeoutIntervalForResource` 
 to make it work as expected. Here is what i am using currently,

```
extension SessionManager {

    /// A `SessionManager` to have a request timeout of 2 minutes.
    static let customDelayed: SessionManager = {
        let secondsInOneMinute = 60
        let numberOfMinutesForTimeout = 2
        let timoutInterval = TimeInterval(numberOfMinutesForTimeout * secondsInOneMinute)

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timoutInterval
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = timoutInterval
        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}
```

Comment: can you link me to documentation about this @Kamran?

Comment: I tried that and all my network request logging tools are still showing 60 seconds (Charles and Netfox) for the timeout

Comment: I am not sure how those networking tools record request timeout. But if you will try on a request that takes more than 60 seconds, it will work with above configuration. You can verify by reducing/increasing request timeout for a request that takes more time.